# How to set delay for animations by justinaguilar.com? [SOLVE]

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, jquery-animate

I was confused How to set delay for animations by  justinaguilar.com.

**My friend found nice solution:**

```
<div class="animate" data-delay="600">HELLO WORLD</div>

<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.animate').each(function(){
  var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

  var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (imagePos < topOfWindow+300) {
      var me = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
      me.addClass("fadeIn");            
      }, $(this).attr("data-delay"));
    } 
    });
  });
  </script>
```

HOPE IT'S VERY HELPFULL!

Comment: Why don't you send it as a separate answer?

Answer (score 0):

For a much simpler solution, especially if you are using Jquery, you can use the Jquery `.delay()` method.